# Xamarin - Clearing the pictures/video cache on ios / Android from media taken by the Media Plugin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, montemagno-media.plugin

I have written a app for ios and Android.  It allows the user to take photos and video with the Media.Plugin library at:  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin
The photos are saved here:
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.idjoey.hempliance/files/Pictures/MyAppname/637542092736259960.jpg

My question is do these pictures stay there until the app is updated or until the person goes into the settings and clears that cache?  Does ios / Android clear it out at any other times?

If I wanted to clear out this cache on ios / Android what would be the best way?

Thanks.

Comment: The storage you provided is Android internal storage. When the app is uninstalled, all the files that are kept on internal storage in that directory will also be deleted.

Comment: But does that happen when a app is updated?  And what about on iOS?  Is this storagae provided by Android and iOS ever get cleaned up automatically?

Comment: As i know, starting with Android 6.0 has automatic backup. Check the link. developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup. On ios, if you saved the data in the file, after upgrade, the file still exists.